# How to add a legend to the side of pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've written this code:

```
labels = [i for i in range(50)]
print(len(labels))

sizes = [28, 63, 1046, 247,511,63,75,154,102,17,115,44,
55,744,13,3,37,1,1837,7,61,1,19,42,17,3,63,21,4,
1,1,1,1,20,427,259,23,38,50,66,14,38,7,4,5,2,6,6,6,18]


#colors
colors = ['#80bcff','#00dbca','#00e56c','#ff9465','#fff400','#ffe4c4',
'#e0eee0','#fff68f','#ffaeb9','#ffa07a',''#48d1cc','#db7093','#bbffff','#ffb5c5','#ffbbff',
'#fa8072','#54ff9f','#fff5ee','#87ceff','#ffe1ff','#ff6347','#eed8ae','#ffff00','#ee82ee',
'#00f5ff','#ee5c42','#d8bfd8','#ee9a49','#5cacee','#9fb6cd','#6ca6cd','#eee5de','#43cd80',
'#cd7054','#436eee','#8b0000','#9b30ff','#ffb5c5','#ffdab9','#90ee90','#db7093']

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
#ax1.pie(sizes, colors = colors, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)

ax1.pie(sizes,colors = colors,startangle=90)


#draw circle
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.70,fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)


# Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle
ax1.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I was trying to add a legend that is to the right of the plot, and lists all 50 labels in a relatively neat fashion in line with the plot (i.e. the legend doesn't run far far longer than the plot).

I'm aware of .legend(), but when I add various .legend() (e.g. when I just add ax1.legend(); similar to [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-a-legend-to-a-matplotlib-plot-in-python), there's no error, there's just no legend either.

Could someone show me how to add a legend to the right of this plot?

Comment: To get the effect you want, you can also similarly pass `labels = labels` to `ax1.legend()` method. Note however, a pie/donut chart with 50 slices is not a good visualization.

Comment: `ax1.legend(labels=labels, loc='center left',  bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), ncol=3)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
labels = [i for i in range(50)]
#print(len(labels))

sizes = [28, 63, 1046, 247,511,63,75,154,102,17,115,44,
55,744,13,3,37,1,1837,7,61,1,19,42,17,3,63,21,4,
1,1,1,1,20,427,259,23,38,50,66,14,38,7,4,5,2,6,6,6,18]


#colors
colors = ['#80bcff','#00dbca','#00e56c','#ff9465','#fff400','#ffe4c4',
'#e0eee0','#fff68f','#ffaeb9','#ffa07a',''#48d1cc','#db7093','#bbffff','#ffb5c5','#ffbbff',
'#fa8072','#54ff9f','#fff5ee','#87ceff','#ffe1ff','#ff6347','#eed8ae','#ffff00','#ee82ee',
'#00f5ff','#ee5c42','#d8bfd8','#ee9a49','#5cacee','#9fb6cd','#6ca6cd','#eee5de','#43cd80',
'#cd7054','#436eee','#8b0000','#9b30ff','#ffb5c5','#ffdab9','#90ee90','#db7093']

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
#ax1.pie(sizes, colors = colors, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)

ax1.pie(sizes,colors = colors,startangle=90)
plt.legend(ax1.patches, labels, ncol=4, bbox_to_anchor=(1,.7))

#draw circle
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.70,fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)


# Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle
ax1.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]